# Problems with Scanner i/o using a text file when passing to an array

Tags: java, arrays, object, io

The actual code works to encode values to the properties of each object within the array.
However, it's using the information from the last line only to populate each value.

```
Scanner data = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("trucklist.txt")));
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) 
{   for(;data.hasNext();)
    {
        t[i].setVin(data.next());
        t[i].setMake(data.next());
        t[i].setModel(data.next());
        t[i].setColor(data.next());
        t[i].setYear(data.next());
        t[i].setBaySize(data.nextDouble());
        t[i].setCabSize(data.nextDouble());

        addElement(t[i]);
    }
}
```

where `trucklist.txt` is :

```
12x4578w Ford F-150 Black 2005 17.2 6.8
12x4589w Ford F-150 Blue 2005 17.2 6.8
12x4587f Ford F-250 Black 2007 60.8 9.5
12x4589z Ford F-150x White 2005 15.4 10.2
```

The array elements are only being populated by the last set of properties for each element. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is currently written, `i` won't increment while there is still data to be read. Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize && data.hasNext(); ++i) {
    // set attributes of t[i]
    addElement(t[i]);
}
```

As a side note, this routine is **very** dependent upon a correctly formatted data file, and will throw unchecked exceptions if the data is malformed.

Comment: the data file is self contained and self defined. additionally, its only going to be used once to populate the array the first time, after which ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream will be initialized for efficiencies sake. I was able to find some local help before referring back to this page in order to make it work, much as you had outlined above, but using a while loop with an embedded incrementer. thank you for taking the time to help a novice.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `FileInputStream` is enough, **no need** to use `DataInputStream` here.

**-** Its always better to use a `Collection` than `array`, as it more flexible.

**See this working code:**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("D:\\text.txt");  ///-----Change the Path here-----///

        ArrayList<String> arList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(f));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

                 arList.add(scan.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(String s : arList){
        System.out.println(s);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: were limited by the instructor to use only self contained and defined arrays so things like arraylist etc are not permissible. I do appreciate the ease that this could have been completed using a predefined class, and thank you for your quick answer.